# Expanding a tag to a larger group of observations

Tags: tags, stata

In an attempt to clean some data I want to mark some observations with a tag. When the variable is negative (for something that should always be positive). This is simple:

```
gen tag = 1 if var<0
```

The issue is that these observations that I am tagging are part of a larger group. These groups are now suspect, and I would like to tag all observations within a group with the same tag (I am assuming that there is group-level measurement error).

How do I think about expanding the tag to other observations within a group, when these specific observations may not actually be negative (and therefore are not tagged)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`egen` (extended generate) is useful for this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
bysort foreign: egen tag = max(price>15000)
```

This will tag all the domestic cars since one of the Cadillac models costs more than 15K.

This greater condition will include missings since Stata thinks of them as very large positive numbers, but this is not an issue here since price is never missing in this data. You could exclude missings with

```
bysort foreign: egen tag = max(price>15000 & !missing(price))
```

Comment: See also the Stata FAQ https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/ in the same spirit as @Dimitriy's helpful answer.